# Why people sometimes use instance variable in non Ruby class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fog

For example, in the code snippets in the [`Fog` gem](http://fog.io/dns/), e.g.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'fog'

# create a connection to the service
dns = Fog::DNS.new({
  :provider     => 'Zerigo',
  :zerigo_email => ZERIGO_EMAIL,
  :zerigo_token => ZERIGO_TOKEN
})


zone = @dns.zones.create(
  :domain => 'example.com',
  :email  => 'admin@example.com'
)
```

Why `dns` is not instance variable at the first place, but then become an instance variable in the next paragraph? Why `zone` is not instance variable?

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens when using an attribute reader/writer, as `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, `attr_accessor`.  These macros create an instance variable and expose for it a 'getter' method, a 'setter' method, or both respectively.  Inside the instance methods, the instance variable will always be accessible.

Regarding the specific code used in the example, it appears that `dns` is a standard local variable.  If it were actually an attribute accessor, it should have been written as:

```
self.dns = Fog::DNS.new({...
```

because the attribute accessor is actually a method, not a local variable.  So you would be correct in stating that it cannot simply 'become' an instance variable after being declared as a local variable, and the sample code as it currently stands is an inaccurate representation of real world use.